# Java POI API - Drawing pie chart in XLS

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have searched for this and implemented it using a template file with sample data and the pie chart in it. I need the following:

1. I want to add more rows (add more data). Modifying the existing data in the defined data range works fine. (Adding extra row by using shiftRows() did not work)
2. I want to move the pie chart in the current sheet. I might have the pie chart in a specific position in the template. But, I need to modify the data and need to move it to a different position within the sheet.

If anyone can provide direction on this or point to a working example, it would be really helpful.

NOTE: I want a pure POI solution.

Comment: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/PieChartDemo.java

Answer (score 1):

Please check if this can help.

[JFreeChart](http://thinktibits.blogspot.in/2012/12/Create-Pie-Chart-Excel-Java-Example.html)

Comment: Thanks for an immediate response. But, I do not want to use JFreeChart. I want a pure POI solution if at all it is available. I updated the question now.